# Subscribed Array doesn't update after called in ngOnIt. Angular

Tags: angular, components

I have an array of objects called Hobby. I am able to set the array of objects when the component first loads. But whenever I go to update that array of objects, I can't.

This is my component that lists an array of Hobbies. Hobby-View-Component. When I ever I make a call to the service component the hobbies[] array never gets updated thus returning a null value in my console.log method.

```
      export class HobbyViewComponent implements OnInit {
  hobbyRoomObj = HobbyRoomObj;
  hobbiesRooms: HobbyRoomObj[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
    this.getHobbies();
  }

  getHobbies()
  {
    console.log("hit2");
    this.data.getHobbiesById().subscribe(data => this.hobbiesRooms = data);
    //console.log(this.hobbiesRooms.length.toString());
  }
```

The url is called and makes valid requests in this Service class next. I know what is being returned works. As mentioned before, this method works in ngOnIt.

```
export class MasterHobbydata {
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("1");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
    this.hobbyListByIdUrl += message;
  }

  //Returns a full list of current hobbies hosted
  getHobbiesById(): Observable<HobbyRoomObj[]> {
    console.log(this.hobbyListByIdUrl);
    return this.http.get<HobbyRoomObj[]>(this.hobbyListByIdUrl)
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        return response;
      }
      )).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getHobbiesById', []))
      );
  }
```

This next component uses a onClick() method to tell the previous component to update. hbv is of type Hobby-View-Component.

```
export class HobbiesComponent implements OnInit {


  onSelect(hobby: hobbyObj): void {
    this.selectedHobby = hobby;
    this.masterhobbydata.changeMessage(this.selectedHobby.HobbyName);
    this.hbv.getHobbies();
  }
```

I hope that i focused on the problem correctly here.

This is my html for the Hobby-View-Component:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbiesRooms">
      <span class="badge">{{hobby.hname}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>
  Message: {{message}}
</p>
```

//////////~~~~~~~!!!! huzzah !!!!~~~~~~~\\\\\\\\\\\\

Updated the Service class by creating a subject of type HobbyRoomObj[] and creating an observable variable. Also, using the Subject method next, I added the requested json object to the Subject of HobbyRooms[].

```
export class MasterHobbydata {

  private hobbies = new Subject<HobbyRoomObj[]>();
  newHobbies = this.hobbies.asObservable();

  //Returns a full list of current hobbies hosted
  getHobbiesById(): Observable<HobbyRoomObj[]> {

    console.log(this.hobbyListByIdUrl);
    return this.http.get<HobbyRoomObj[]>(this.hobbyListByIdUrl)
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        this.hobbies.next(response);
        return response;
      }
      )).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getHobbiesById', []))
      );
  }

}
```

In Hobby-View-Component.ts I subscribed to the newHobbies Observable of the Service Component inside ngOnInIt. Then whenever I click on a new hobby, I subscribe the GetHobbiesById and update the list.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
    console.log("hit2");
    this.data.newHobbies.subscribe(
      data => {this.hobbiesRooms = data;
      });
  }

  getHobbies()
  {

    this.data.getHobbiesById().subscribe(
      data => {this.hobbiesRooms = data;
      console.log(this.hobbiesRooms);
      });
  }
```

I guess my only curiosity is why I am subscribing twice. Am I correct in thinking that I'm subscribing to the hobbyroomobj[] and then subscribing to the method gethobbiesbyId()?

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the console.log inside the subscribe,

```
this.data.getHobbiesById().subscribe(
data => this.hobbiesRooms = data;
console.log(this.hobbiesRooms);
);
```

Comment: Although, this doesn't solve my problem I appreciate your input. The only problem is the syntax doesn't seem to work. Could you help further explain why my previous console.log was not working correctly?

Comment: @user9639000 because you are having the console.log outside the subscribr where this.hobbiesRooms is not defined since the service returns data asynchronously

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense. I fixed the syntax and now I see what you are saying. I guess I'm still having a hard time understanding why the html of ul is not being updated now. But, this helps me understands subscribed observables. Can I say that? Subscribed observable?

Comment: The Hobby-View-Component.html is not updating for some reason. From what I have so far, The first HobbiesComponent has a list of hobbies, when one of those hobbies is selected (onSelect) it tells the Hobby-View-Component to call a service that subscribes a local array of hobbies to an observable that makes a get request to my local server.     But the list never updates.

Comment: is your variable a subject?

Comment: Hobby-View-Component calls getHobbies in ngOnInIt and a list appears in the Hobby-View-Component from a default url. But when i click on a hobby in the Main Component List, the list that is in the Hobby-View-Component does not update. I'm not sure if my technical vocabulary is up to date. Bear with me i'm knew to angular and typescript.

Comment: the variable that is being updated through the subscriber? So, this.data.getHobbiesById().subscribe(data => this.hobbiesRooms = data);  ? this.hobbiesRooms is instantiated as a regular array of Object type.

Comment: I did create a Subject for another Observable of type string. 
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("1");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();                                                  I'm just having a hard time understanding how I can create a Subject of Hobby[] since BehaviorSubject can only take a single value.